# Correct return type for a property of an object

Tags: typescript

Given the following example code:

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const foo: Foo = { name: 'lorem', age: 123 };

const useObject = <T>(obj: T) => {
    const getValue = (key: keyof T): [RETURN HERE] => {
        return obj[key];
    }
    return { getValue };
}

const { getValue } = useObject<Foo>(foo);
getValue('name');
```

What would I need to replace `[RETURN HERE]` with to give an accurate return type? For example, the type of `getValue('name')` would be `string` and the type of `getValue('age')` would be `number`.

Comment: Return type annotations are optional. They are inferred by the compiler.

Comment: @AluanHaddad If you don't annotate it correctly here then it will be `string | number`.

Comment: @catgirlkelly not so. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3PsnHeYQK7EBG0TAvrlwJ0IashiYKGLAF4chEuwDkAG3RQIxZQBoWbCgEYATAGZk-JsNHiOlCAHluAKwgIwyeQB4AKgD4ACnQXCh8ASk8-HGYRMQ82MAA1OFUOFG8AaWQIAA9IEAATSmQAawgAT3QYZH8AsvKKDIjZKLwCAk0wDigQZGDnAG16gF0mAktmTu7e7GQE5NSUCYnrOIV5lLSLT2Q7Rxc3MC8ZQMl0MKtY8TgKEC5eKB2NxYDlVghlC9XxEApqWhAdCeECSmwgryIpE+DCAA

Comment: I guess this is miscommunication. I was referring to how the program is in its current state, while you have used a generic there. Your point is valid for sure but I like to annotate it here to be explicit (and also it would type-check the body of the function).

Comment: @catgirlkelly I brought it up because type inference will tell you the return type of the function because in many cases, like this one, the compiler knows more than the author. After reading the inferred type you can choose whether or not to write it down explicityl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generic to "store" what `key` is, then use it in the return type:

```
const getValue = <K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] => {
    return obj[key];
};
```

And as @AluanHaddad points out, for this case you don't actually need the return type to be explicitly annotated:

```
// automatically inferred to return T[K]
const getValue = <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNwHHJyNUkCuZARtFb4AvgQIJ0IOshiZqGLAF4cJctwDkAG3RQIZDQBoOXagEYATAGZkI4RKkyeNCAHl+AKwgIwyFQB4AFQA+AAp0T2pAgEo-YJw2YklpXy4wADU4LR4UAIBpZAgAD0gQABMaZABrCABPdBhkENCa2uo86KiAbTyAXTiEwnZiPTAeKBBkCI8u1t7hdjtxIaJR8cnsZDTM7JQl0WXkmU3trJzbP2RnN09vMH9FMLl0aPt8U93QjVIKDVegA)

Answer (score 2):

It will not be enough to just paste the return type, because `keyof T` is not strict enough to infer the type of value based on the key.

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const foo: Foo = { name: 'lorem', age: 123 };

const useObject = <T,>(obj: T) => {
    const getValue = <K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] => {
        return obj[key];
    }
    return { getValue };
}

const { getValue } = useObject<Foo>(foo);
getValue('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a generic type `K` for the function `getValue` which only allows keys of `T` to be passed to the function. Afterwards return the type `T[K]`.

```js
const useObject = <T,>(obj: T) => {
    const getValue = <K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] => {
        return obj[key];
    }
    return { getValue };
}
```