# React Typescript - render function not applying types correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a minimal reproducible example of the problem at the following link:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type InputValue = string[] | string;

interface InputProps<T extends InputValue> {
    value: T;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// TEXT INPUT
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const TextInput = ({ value = '' }: InputProps<string>): React.ReactElement => {
    return <input value={value} />;
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FORM FIELD
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

interface FormFieldProps<T extends InputValue> {
    render: (props: InputProps<T>) => React.ReactElement;
    value: T;
}

const FormField = <T extends InputValue>({
    render,
    value,
}: FormFieldProps<T>): React.ReactElement => (
    <div>
        {render({ value })}
    </div>
);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FORM
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

interface FieldPropsReturn<T> {
    value: T[keyof T];
}

interface UseFormReturn<T> {
    fieldProps: (name: keyof T) => FieldPropsReturn<T>;
}

const useForm = <T extends object>(): UseFormReturn<T> => {
    const [formData] = useState<T>({} as T);

    const fieldProps = (name: keyof T): FieldPropsReturn<T> => ({
        value: formData[name],
    });

    return {
        fieldProps
    };
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// INDEX
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

interface IndexFormFields {
    fruits: string[];
    name: string;
}

const Index = (): React.ReactElement => {
    const { fieldProps } = useForm<IndexFormFields>();

    return (
        <FormField
            {...fieldProps('name')}
            render={(props): React.ReactElement => <TextInput {...props} />}
        />
    );
};

export default Index;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SMxXV+g06ADWSAEEDo6T0mWpPbp-bgXWIwZAI7+YnHn11dDD7OlErEKGeaTnC6XHlOScH5-2hH3Y8Vq5NEymRCQu62p43gOoEwQQAARgAVkgGCRIs5xbjujIfoeipJse8SmlMOh0IyxIUCgBgqP+ZAUEgkbLLQKDBI+Fi6th8Cnta8q2osV43nAd6LukiEvvKqHju8yaYbqcRTvQ+GEToHFIHoPq6tQNZ8LqPwHhOYlxMxQ5vu61BwjkdadsZ7Zoh0xItG2JnWZSa7WH29hej4u4vsEon0FA+DADAMomMcugru6slpEcZjfoxfJOWxiGqrccaPAmbxCgxv7wHg2mvq4NC2v+u5uOITkuWehDwcp7pqf8ybZvEbhFda1WaTg1zNRl8qLCwsksCWDViXmUDgpK0oxTGcVXPGWpJp4Mw7LgzXXFKb7QpEpaaXAMLusp+l8L4kCwHAXq2PgcjwAVvi8EAA)

Essentially, I am building some form helpers, including a `FormField` that renders a form component. I would like these `FormField` render functions to infer the value type from the key passed to `fieldProps`, but at the moment it is returning the following error on the `TextInput` component:

```
Type '{ value: string | string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'InputProps<string>'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Is there any way that a render function for a `FormField` with a `fieldProps` of 'name' will pass a value type of `string`, and one with a `fieldProps` of 'fruits' will pass a value type of `string[]`, as per the `IndexFormFields` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a generic to `fieldProps`, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118240/correct-return-type-for-a-property-of-an-object/72118287#72118287) answer:

```
    const fieldProps = <Name extends keyof T>(name: Name): FieldPropsReturn<T, Name> => ({
        value: formData[name],
    });
```

You would also need to update the interface to reflect this:

```
interface FieldPropsReturn<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    value: T[K];
}
```

The return type on `useForm` is also not needed, but if you must, you have to also change the type of `fieldProps` there.

Now when you use your component, you get no errors. And if you use it incorrectly, you get errors.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TzYADS3gdgWCAGskAIIHR0raF0uV4qYrq-QadBO9JlqT26f24F1iMGQCO-mJI9v4nQw+zpWk3O0UM9p-5eevl+lIkWMRP1SOAP2eU4k0HF99kIG8xw8bBwKQWEjTGCYpiIJAr1tTxv0dOAIAAIwAKyQDBAMg94HziU0ph0OhGWJCgUAMFQsLICgkEjZZaBQYIPBrPhdTo+An2teVcOQ-DZzgP9N0A4DnjSZDzgxZ95Xgu9ELAkDomot1dR3ZI0kYkNmPIHQlKQPQfV1aghPdH5bxoozxKHWD3WoOEcjrTt-PbNEOmJFo2wC8LKWPaw+3sL0fCvaDgk+XUGHwYAYBlExjl0Q93WstIjjMI8TQw+BxDi21FjU1VbjjR4EzeIURNK3B6A06UaFtLCrzccrfAS59CEoixdWc-5kzcLMjPiNwButbNptwa5lvcmDXEWFhrJYEsFumvMoHBSVpWqmNaqueMtSTTwZh2JblqlWDoUiUtFphXbATmtl3pzZbrlW+UNtS9LCG2l7Fu+HlaUOh7XBOq4zvuerLuo66-FunBfphwgnrBoy3rLGEhO8vhfEgWA4C9Wx8DkMqxR8XggA)